# Passing Context information to task in DataBricks Workflows

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I need in my task the scheduling date of the job run to run queries based on a timestamp. Is there a way to do it with Parameters?

[image: Adding parameters to task]

I am able to set the start-time (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-engineering/jobs/jobs#task-parameter-variables). But I need the exact scheduling time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are asking this because your job has several tasks.
If that's the case, you can use [Dbutils.jobs.taskvalues](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#taskvalues-subutility-dbutilsjobstaskvalues) for doing so, in the first task of your job, you can get the current timestamp as the first command executed and then set a ***job taskValue***:

```
from datetime import datetime

utc_timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
dbutils.jobs.taskValues.set("job_start_timestamp", utc_timestamp)
```

And in the other task in which you want to make use of these values:

```
job_start_timestamp = dbutils.jobs.taskValues.get(taskKey="first_task_name",key="job_start_timestamp")
```

Answer (score 0):

The schedule date/time is set at the job or workflow level. Not at the task level.